# access string names using variables in FOR statement

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

is is possible to access objects using variables in a FOR statement?

Say i have declared:

```
UIImageView *UIImageView0;
UIImageView *UIImageView1;
UIImageView *UIImageView2;
```

and i have 3 objects in an array and i call a FOR statement if x in the array is equal to 2 i want it to add the value of x to the UIImageView name like UIImageView1 etc

I have tried:

```
for (int x=0; x<[theArray count]; x++) {

UIImageView[x].image = etc....

}
```

but it gives me a error on UIImageView[x]

```
subscript requires size of interface 'UIImageView'
```

any ideas? or is it even possible with a UIImageView?

Thanks

Comment: where is your array declared?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You *don't* have three elements in an array, though; you have three independent variables with similar names. If you created an *actual* array, containing the values of the three variables, then you could use the `for` loop -- and in fact, the syntax would be just as you've shown (using the actual name of the array variable, of course.)

You could say

```
UIImageView * views[3] = {UIImageView0, UIImageView1, UIImageView2};
```

and then use, for example, `views[i].image` in your loop.

Comment: And to get the number of views in that array, use `sizeof(views) / sizeof(views[0])`.

Comment: This worked perfectly thank you. i knew it was possible but didn't know how to go about it, its simple now i look at it

Answer (score 2):

In order to put your UIImageView into an array you need to create an instance NSMutableArray (for instance)

The above code does not show any array, instead you have three ivars

```
UIImageView *UIImageView0;
UIImageView *UIImageView1;
UIImageView *UIImageView2;
```

and to access those you would use the name, not an array.

If you however put them into an `NSMutableArray` you can access them using

```
NSMutableArray array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] 
   initWithObjects:UIImageView0, UIImageView1, UIImageView2, nil];
[array objectAtIndex:i ]; // where i is 0,1 or 2

...
[array release];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put your UIImageView to another array, and get the UIImageView from that array.

```
NSArray *imagesArray = @[imageView0, ...]

for(size_t i = 0; i<theArray.count; i++)
{
    UIImageView *imageView = [imagesArray objectAtIndex:i];
}
```

Or you can use the "tag" property of UIView like:

```
UIImageView *image0 = ...;
image0.tag = 100; //or 0 or something else
[self.view addSubview:image0];
```

And then get the UIImageView by tag in your FOR statement:

```
for(size_t i = 0; i<theArray.count; i++)
{
    UIImageView *imageView = [self.view viewWithTag:100+i];
}
```

Comment: Isn't this nicer with FastEnumeration? for (UIImageView *imageView in imagesArray) { }

Comment: The array literal is `@[...]`, `@{...}` is for dictionaries. And it works only in the as-of-yet-unrelease Xcode 4.5.

Comment: Actually it works for Xcode 4.4 as well, which is also unreleased :)

Comment: @TobiasHieta I just illustrated simple way and yeah for sure FastEnumeration is nicer.